# Using the style of the inherited control

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

My first firemonkey component is inherited from a TSpinBox but I cannot figure out how to get it to use the same style as the base component.
At design time in my app I can set the StyleLookup to "spinboxstyle" and get the correct style but if I try to do that in the constructor for the new component it ignores it.
What is the correct procedure for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor is the correct place.

```
You have to use FStyleLookup := 'spinboxstyle';  (Note the F)
Not StyleLookup := 'spinboxstyle';
```